# verifying a wallet A's BIP39 seed phrase by restoring to another wallet while wallet 'A' is still active. OK to do? Wallet 'A' funds remain safe?

Tags: backup, cryptocurrency

I'm playing around with crypto, and I bought a cold storage wallet (call it wallet 'A') and added a moderate amount  of funds to it.   I am considering adding more funds, but before I do I want to triple check that  i have the seed phrase down correctly and that the restore process works in the event that wallet 'A' gets trampled by rhinos or some other terrible thing happens.

So, my question is:  as a test, can I restore the BIP39 standard-based 12 word seed phrase that I chose to a second wallet that supports BIP39  SIMULTANEOUSLY with having my funds safe and sound in wallet 'A' ?      I don't want to lose the funds I have, but I do want to verify the restore process before adding more.

thanks in advance !